# How do I use sql COUNT for Mage::getModel()->getCollection();?

Tags: magento

I want to know how to use arregate sql functions for when making a Magento module. I currently have this code inside my mode;

```
$rake = Mage::getModel('showdown/votes')->getCollection();
$rake->addFieldToFilter('votedfor', $productid);
//$collection->groupByFilter('matchid'); //<-- what do i put here?
$sticks = count($rake);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve as the title of you question conflicts with the code example provided.

The title asks how to count a collection, and your code example asks how to perform a group by.

So,

**Collection Count**

`count($collection)`, `$collection->count()` or simply `$collection->getSize()` which will avoid the collection load (ideal if you simply require the count and nothing else)

**Group By**

*EAV Based Collection:*

```
    $collection->groupByAttribute('matchid');
```

*Non EAV Based Collection:*

```
    $collection->getSelect()->group('matchid');
```

Comment: What's the difference between EAV and non-EAV? And more importantly, why is there both?

Comment: Your module will most likely not be using EAV, i added for the sake of completeness.  Have a look at the following which should explain things: http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/magento-database-structure-eav.html  - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value/

Comment: I need to get `$collection->setPage(0, 10);` to work on my non-EAV model and it doesn't work. I've tried and `$matches->getSelect()->setPage(0, 10);` and it doesn't help.

Comment: Ill gladly answer for you if you can put this into a separate question as its an entirely unrelated question.

Comment: Done. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510927/how-do-i-use-setpage-in-an-non-eav-model-in-magento-for-pagination-limiting