# How do I use setPage() in an non-EAV model in Magento for pagination/limiting?

Tags: magento

I need to get `$collection->setPage(0, 10);` to work on my non-EAV model and it doesn't work. I've tried and `$matches->getSelect()->setPage(0, 10);` and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setPage()` method only works for EAV based collection in Magento because it is defined in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` class...

```
public function setPage($pageNum, $pageSize)
{
    $this->setCurPage($pageNum)
        ->setPageSize($pageSize);
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, its a nice shorthand utility that is available to EAV based collections.  For your non EAV based collection you can create your own version of this in your collection class or use the more verbose syntax for setting the page number and size in your client code when initialising the collection:

```
$collection->setCurPage($pageNum)
           ->setPageSize($pageSize)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updateIndex()
{
    $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'url_key', 'price', 'visibility'));

    $productsCollection->setPageSize(100);

    $pages = $productsCollection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;

    do {
        $productsCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);
        $productsCollection->load();

        foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {

            $insertData = array(
                'entity_id' => $_product->getId(),
                'title' => $_product->getName(),
                'image' => $_product->getImage(),
                'url' => $_product->getUrlKey(),
                'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
            );

            $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate(
                $this->getTable('atwix_sonar/suggestions'),
                $insertData,
                array('title', 'image', 'url', 'price')
            );
        }

        $currentPage++;
        //clear collection and free memory
        $productsCollection->clear();
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
}
```

See this complete example, it illustrates exactly how to use magento collection pager functions.
Source : http://www.atwix.com/magento/working-with-large-collections/